# Unpleasant moderator behaviour

Tags: discussion

My first ever post to this site was an answer yesterday to [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/33384/20927) about a Soviet propaganda poster. I put some effort into this, and I think my post was well received. As I pointed out myself, it was not actually an answer to the question, but it contained pertinent information, and as it didn't fit into a comment, I posted it as an answer. Then Moderator T.E.D. came along and relegated it to the comments ("I've gone and moved this one for you", like they were doing me a favour).

Well, this undid all my work, so I rescued my post from the comments. Then along came Moderator T.E.D. again, and deleted my post outright. I wish to register my protest at this high-handed behaviour. Oh, and my question is: Can Moderator T.E.D. be overruled?

Comment: The difficulty is that those posts aren't really answers. They add a bit of information, which is better suited for a comment or, perhaps, [chat]. If you were able to address the question (who made the poster) it would help. Please see: [answer].

Comment: "As I pointed out myself, it was not actually an answer. . .  " - there are rules for the site; one of those rules is that answers should be answers. According to the rules, your answer should have been outright deleted.  T.E.D. helped you by preserving the content.  He acted like he did you a favor because he did you a favor. I valued your contribution, but I think TED did right.

Comment: What was unpleasant? Why are you adamant that the information didn't fit into a comment? Help me to understand why you are offended.

Comment: The layout of the post is important. As a comment it is very difficult to read, so much so that I would call it ugly. Compare the answer (if you can still see it) with this:...

Comment: (Not an answer, but some of you might be interested.) The Cyrillic text reads: > Da zdravstvuyet druzhba narodov SSSR i Kitaya! meaning "Long live the friendship of the peoples of the USSR and China!" The Chinese text reads: > 中蘇两國人民友誼萬歳 ! In pinyin: > Zhōng-sū liǎng guó rénmín yǒuyì wànsuì! or "Chinese-Soviet twin nations people's friendship long-live!" Characters 蘇, 國, 誼, 萬, and 歳 are traditional; only character 两 is simplified. (The remaining four characters were not changed in the Great Simplification.)

Comment: Keeping the answers section reserved for answers is also important.

Comment: @TonyK Would you mind if I add this as extra information in the question? I will cite you as the source. Then the info stays in the open and is well formatted, and it improves the question. Perhaps it will improve the ability of another user to find the correct answer.

Comment: @axsvl77: I would be delighted if you did that!

Comment: @TonyK ok, I added your text to the question. Please take a look and feel free to edit it if you think there is a better way to format it.

Comment: And I want to apologize -  I was thinking of moving the information to the question before the hassle, but I'm still fairly new to SE so I wasn't sure about how to make such a  request. And as far as Ted and other moderators, they are working hard to keep spam and poor questions away, and try to improve the quality of the site. I hope you will stick around and confirm for yourself that they are in fact decent, high quality people.

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand what the problem is here. You knowingly abused the system and posted a non answer as an answer - *twice*. T.E.D. was correct in removing it, both times.

I realize that the comment section is limited, and that your comment may have benefited from features reserved for actual posts. That however is not an excuse to abuse the system or accuse a moderator of "unpleasant behaviour" when all they did was follow the site's rules & guidelines.